# How to provide a derived instance with an ancestor field declaration?

Tags: delphi, inheritance

I am having some trouble figuring out this case of inheritance.

In my class `TBalans`, I have a routine `Initialiseer` that takes a `TBalPar` object as parameter. `TBalPar` is the ancestor class of `TNewBalPar` that has additional fields. Now I would like to reach the additional fields from within my `TBalans` class. I still can feed a `TNewBalPar` object to the `Initialiseer` routine, but how do I get to the data of the descendant class?

What I tried is the following: I derived `TBalans` too into `TNieuweBalans`, gave it the new additional fields, and assign them in the routine:

```
type
  TBalPar = class
    //some vars
  end;

  TNewBalPar = class(TBalPar)
    ExtraVar: TValue;
  end;

  TBalans = class
    MyBalPar: TBalPar;
    function Initialiseer(ABalPar: TBalPar): Boolean; virtual;
  end;

  TNieuweBalans = class(TBalans)
    MyBalPar: TNewBalpar;  //declared again so I don't need to cast it when using it
    MyExtraVar: TValue;
    function Initialiseer(ABalPar: TBalPar): Boolean; override;
  end;

  function TBalans.Initialiseer(ABalPar: TBalPar): Boolean;
  begin
    MyBalPar := ABalPar;
  end;

  function TNieuweBalans.Initialiseer(ABalPar: TBalPar): Boolean;
  begin
    inherited;
    MyBalPar := TNewBalPar(ABalPar);
    MyExtraVar := MyBalPar.ExtraVar;  //instead of casting TNewBalPar(MyBalPar).ExtraVar
  end;
```

This code works, but it feels wrong: I declare the `MyBalPar` field twice. I would like to improve on it.

Note that I am not looking for a way how to expose `ExtraVar` to the outside world, but how to use it conveniently within `TNieuweBalans`.

How can I eliminate the double `MyBalPar` field but still prevent frequent typecasting?

Comment: Let me get this straight. You want your TNieuweBalans class to directly expose the ExtraVar from internal class of TNewBalpar type? It it is so then I recomend you turn MyExtraVar field into property and then use getter/setter mothods to directly read/write field of internal class of TNewBaplar. If you go this way don't forget about safety mechanizm which will fist check if the internal clas has already been assigned before trying to read/write its fields so you don't get AV when internal calss isn't assigned.

Comment: Lots of possible solutions. Hard to recommend one without more context.

Comment: With a call like this example you would work in the nirvana`var
 p:TBalpar; begin
   p:=TBalpar.Create;
   with TNieuweBalans.Create do Initialiseer(p);
end;`

Comment: Agreed with @DavidHeffernan - this is an open-ended question about working code that is soliciting opinion about possible design changes.  As such, without specific context or a specific problem to solve there are too many possible answers to make this a valid question.

Comment: ok, i will give some more detail on how the parameter is used. at silverwarrior : the point is not really exposing the ExtraVar, i'ts more about using it in the new class.

Answer (score 2):

#### Current design

The need for a convenient designated derived field type for an ancestral field is not forbidden, nor uncommon for that matter. But your implementation, like you sense already, has some problems:

- the doubled fields require unnecessary memory,
- you need to synchronize changes to `TBalans.MyBalPar` and `TNieuweBalans.MyBalPar`,
- you need to synchronize changes to `TNieuweBalans.MyBalPar.ExtraVar` and `TNieuweBalans.MyExtraVar`,
- you do not enforce the derived class type: feeding a `TBalPar` object to `TNieuweBalans.Initialiseer` results in an access violation because `MyBalPar.ExtraVar` does not exist.

There are multiple ways to overcome each of these problems.

The most elementary solution to prevent extra fields is to provide properties for them with getters that extract the values from the inherited class (I renamed some of your types and variables for comprehensibility):

```
type
  TBalPar = class(TObject)
    // some variables
  end;

  TBalParEx = class(TBalPar)
  private
    FExtra: TValue;
  public
    property Extra: TValue read FExtra write FExtra;
  end;

  TBalance = class(TObject)
  private
    FBalPar: TBalPar;
  public
    function Initialize(ABalPar: TBalPar): Boolean; virtual;
    property BalPar: TBalPar read FBalPar;
  end;

  TBalanceEx = class(TBalance)
  private
    function GetExtra: TValue;
    procedure SetExtra(Value: TValue);
  public
    function BalPar: TBalParEx;
    function Initialize(ABalPar: TBalPar): Boolean; override;
    property Extra: TValue read GetExtra write SetExtra;
  end;

function TBalanceEx.BalPar: TBalParEx;
begin
  Result := TBalParEx(inherited BalPar);
end;

function TBalanceEx.GetExtra: TValue;
begin
  Result := BalPar.Extra;
end;

procedure TBalanceEx.SetExtra(Value: TValue);
begin
  BalPar.Extra := Value;
end;
```

With this approach, there is only one typecast needed and it does not require additional storage.

To enforce `TBalanceEx.BalPar` to be of type `TBalParEx`, you could raise an exception in the `Initialize` routine:

```
function TBalance.Initialize(ABalPar: TBalPar): Boolean;
begin
  FBalPar := ABalPar;
  Result := True;
end;

function TBalanceEx.Initialize(ABalPar: TBalPar): Boolean;
begin
  if ABalPar is TBalParEx then
    Result := inherited Initialize(ABalPar)
  else
    raise Exception.Create('Wrong BalPar type');
end;
```

Of course, this places the sole responsibility of a correct class functioning on the requirement to always call the `Initialize` routine before any other usage of the other class members. Since that is what initialization obviously is intended for, you could ignore that, but protection against misuse could be added like:

```
  TBalance = class(TObject)
  protected
    function HasBalPar: Boolean; virtual;
    ...

  TBalanceEx = class(TBalance)
  protected
    function HasBalPar: Boolean; override;
    ...

function TBalance.HasBalPar: Boolean;
begin
  Result := FBalPar is TBalPar;
end;

function TBalance.Initialize(ABalPar: TBalPar): Boolean;
begin
  FBalPar := ABalPar;
  Result := HasPalBar;
end;

function TBalanceEx.GetExtra: TValue;
begin
  if HasBalPar then
    Result := BalPar.Extra
  else
    Result := nil;
end;

function TBalanceEx.HasBalPar: Boolean;
begin
  Result := BalPar is TBalParEx;
end;

function TBalanceEx.Initialize(ABalPar: TBalPar): Boolean;
begin
  Result := inherited Initialize(ABalPar);
  if Result = False then
    raise Exception.Create('Initialization went wrong');
end;

procedure TBalanceEx.SetExtra(Value: TValue);
begin
  if HasBalPar then
    BalPar.Extra := Value;
end;
```

In turn, this requires not to forget to implement `HasBalPar` for each derived class. You could 'protect' against that with:

```
  TBalance = class(TObject)
  strict private
    function HasBalPar: Boolean;
  private
    ...

  TBalanceEx = class(TBalance)
  strict private
    function HasBalPar: Boolean;
  private
    ...
```

#### Design considerations

All in all, making this a robust design requires some work. And your current approach raises the question why you would want to have the `Extra` field in the `TBalanceEx` class too. Even why to have a `TBalanceEx` class at all.

From the naming of your classes, I assume you have the following equivalent: A structure which has structural parameters like build date, owner, location, and you have a specialized structure, say a castle, with additional parameters like the number of towers and whether it has a moat:

- TStructureData: Location, BuildDate
- TCastleData: Location, BuildDate, TowerCount, HasMoat
- TStructure: StructureData
- TCastle: StructureData, CastleData

The question you need to answer is whether a structure needs to know if it is a castle, or a palace, a warehouse, a biological or chemical structure. Assume your program evolves to being able to handle all different kinds of structures, then you are always bound to add two classes to your program, resulting in a more and more complex and improvised design which in the end will get you in trouble, if not already. The challenge is to make this a more generalized and abstract design.

For example:

- must `TStructureData` and `TStructure` be separate classes?
- could calculations, analysations, or presentational requests on the specific data be 'outsourced' to the specific class? E.g.: if you add a `GetFeatures` routine to the `TStructureData` class, then the `TStructure` class can request the features of a `TCastle` without knowing it being a Castle.
- ...

Think big.

Comment: Thanks for you great answer, when I implement it, I will check it as accepted. But all the detailed info is greatly appreciated.